# How to call sessionStorage from a Firefox Addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, session-storage

I am trying to call [sessionStorage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage#sessionStorage) in my addon (here is the demo https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/154290/latest/), but nothing gets stored. Any tips?

```
 var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Check with Proofread Bot",
    context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
               '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                '  sessionStorage.setItem("proofread_bot_chrome", text);' +
                '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                        '});',
    onMessage: function(text) {
        tabs.open("http://proofreadbot.com");                    }                        
    }) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are never shared across different domains. That also applies to content scripts injected into pages from different domains, content scripts run with the privileges of these pages and only have access to the same `sessionStorage` as the pages themselves. You need to use proper messaging as explained in the [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634068/785541).