# How to pass a value between browser tabs?

Tags: firefox, tabs, firefox-addon, clipboard, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to pass a value from one tab to another.

I tried `sessionStorage` and clipboard, but no luck so far. Here is the demo, and the code as well:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/154290/latest/

What it tries to do is get the selected text, and pass it to the opened tab:

```js
// Create a new context menu item.
var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
    label: "Check with Proofread Bot",
    context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
    contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                '  sessionStorage.setItem("proofread_bot_chrome", text);' +
                '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                        '});',
    onMessage: function(text) {
        clipboard.set(text);
        //sessionStorage.setItem("proofread_bot_chrome", text);
        tabs.open({
          url: "http://proofreadbot.com",
          onOpen: function onOpen(tab) {
            // do stuff like listen for content
            // loading.
            alert(clipboard.get());
            alert(selection.text);
            sessionStorage.setItem("proofread_bot_chrome", clipboard.get());
          }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I went with Firefox clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` are always bound to a domain. Content scripts run with the privileges of the web page meaning that they access the session storage for that web page - not very useful to pass data around. And they simply don't have clipboard access.

This means that you can't get around "traditional" messaging. When you open the tab you should attach a content script, wait for it to be ready (the content script can send a message to indicate that) and send it the text. Something like this:

```js
onOpen: function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScript: "self.on('message', function(text) {alert(text);});" +
                   "self.postMessage(null);",
    onMessage: function() {
      worker.postMessage(text);
    }
  });
}
```

For reference: [Communicating using `postMessage()`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html)

Comment: Have you try with only `alert(text)` in contentScript ?

Comment: @CharlesJourdan: If you are asking me - no, I didn't. This content script will cause an error message like "text is not defined". Why should it produce anything else?

Comment: mmmh I'm not sure but when I test with only alert I see an about:blank page before the correct page. Maybe if you put the `worker.postMessage(text);` on the ready event it will be better.

Comment: @CharlesJourdan: We are talking about the Firefox Add-on SDK, not about frames...

Comment: I know and I talk about this too. Anyway it was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should try localStorage instead of sessionStorage. localStorage is shared between the documents from same origin. 
Although it persists even on tab close, which may or may not be desirable depending on your requirement.

sessionStorage is per document, and hence not shared between tabs.

Comment: They aren't in the same domain so this isn't going to help.